# Azure DevOps Pipeline AKS Release Deploy

Tags: azure-devops, cicd

[image]I use Release pipelines to deploy my apps to AKS. After the build pipeline is finished then trigger release.I saw that all artifacts are already there.The deploy release pipeline is simple. Agency Job, Create Secret Job, and deploy to Kubernetes job.The error happens in the Deployment job

> 2022-12-04T15:28:24.9668012Z ##[error]error: must specify one of -f and -k
> [command]/usr/local/bin/kubectl apply -f  --namespace dev

The app is based on .Net6 and I use the Manifests folder with one yml. Why apply -f does not find my deployment.yml. I put him here in input Manifests field $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Service/Manifests/dev/deployment.yml
deployment:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-deployment-dev
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service-dev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service-dev
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service-dev
        image: registry.azurecr.io/service-dev
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-cluster-dev
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: service-dev
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: service-dev
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue when using the Kubectl task and apply command.

The cause of the issue could be that you specified the deployment.yml file in the wrong field of task.

[image]

To solve this issue, you need to enable the **Use configuration** option and set the deployment.yml path.

For example:

[image]

Or you can change to use the task: **Deploy to Kubernetes**  to deploy to AKS.  In this task, you can directly define the deployment.yml file in the task. And this is required.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had an assignment where I have use classic pipeline to deploy application into AKS.
Please find the following build and release pipeline.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]